# How to understand Titus 3:10 in light of Matthew 18:15-17?

Tags: matthew, titus

Titus 3:10 NIV

> ***Warn a divisive person once, and then warn them a second time***. After that, have nothing to do with them.

In the above text it seems only two warnings are given yet in the Matthew text it seems one has to go out of his way to convince him before abandoning him

Matthew 18:15-17 NIV

> “If your brother or sister[b] sins,[c] go and point out their fault, just between the two of you. If they listen to you, you have won them over. 16 But if they will not listen, take one or two others along, so that ‘every matter may be established by the testimony of two or three witnesses.’[d] 17 If they still refuse to listen, tell it to the church; and if they refuse to listen even to the church, treat them as you would a pagan or a tax collector.

How can one understand the above texts?

Comment: Is this intended as a Contradiction question? These texts aren't by the same author or on the same topic, I'm struggling to see the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two texts, Titus 3:10 and Matt 18:15-17 are discussing completely different situations and so there is no contradiction.

**Titus 3:10 - Reject a divisive person after a first and second warning**

This is discussing a person who deliberately causes division in the church; that is, destroyed unity by either undermining authority, tells lies, or preaches heresy, etc, etc. (Unfortunately, there are many ways to be divisive.)

> Matt 18: **15**If your brother sins against you, go and confront him
> privately. If he listens to you, you have won your brother over.
> **16** But if he will not listen, take one or two others along, so that ‘every matter may be established by the testimony of two or three
> witnesses.’ **17** If he refuses to listen to them, tell it to the
> church. And if he refuses to listen even to the church, regard him as
> you would a pagan or a tax collector.

This text is discussing a personal sin such a cheating, lying, stealing, adultery, blasphemy, etc.  Such a person must be dealt with promptly else it can lead to divisiveness.

Now, while these two texts are discussing different situations, they can actually be treated in the same way - the two warnings for a divisive person are at the church level already and may be preceded by private discussions.

Thus, there is no conflict between these two texts.